# Load/Save NSUserDefaults Array - Bools?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

So, I have an application that I'm building which includes a checklist of 100 items.

I wish to create an array of `bools` which indicate whether or not an item is "checked", then save it to the device using `NSUserDefaults` so it can be loaded each time the app is run.

I understand by reading around that you cannot store bool values in NSArrays so I opted of a mutable array which holds strings `@"YES"` and `@"NO"`... I'm almost certain this is a bad way of doing it but I'm out of ideas.

I create my array like this:

```
boolArrayOfCheckList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        [boolArrayOfCheckList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NO"]];      
    }
```

When an item is checked using an `IBAction`, it updates the array at the index associated with the button (this appears to be adding to the array instead of replacing the object at said index :( ...):

```
[boolArrayOfCheckList insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"YES"] atIndex:0];
```

Then save the array like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:boolArrayOfCheckList forKey:@"myBoolArray"];
```

When I reload the application, the `ViewdidLoad` loads the key:

```
NSMutableArray *boolArrayOfCheckList = (NSMutableArray *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myBoolArray"];
```

and comparing the element like this and loading the items check/uncheck accordingly:

```
if([[boolArrayOfCheckList objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"YES"]) ... //do this
```

But I'm getting some funny results when I add strings and I'm having trouble loading the data again.

There must be a better more efficient way of storing a checklist in an array that can be saved/updated accordingly. How can this be done?

Thank you.

**Update**

Just noticed I was inserting instead of replacing, so that explains the array getting bigger instead of replacing the object at a specific index. Now doing this:

```
[boolArrayOfCheckList replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"YES"]];
```

Comment: It's best to use `NSNumber` to wrap `BOOL`s for an `NSArray`. However, using an array to hold whether an item has been checked or not sounds error-prone; the only thing relating the items to the checklist is their position in the array. Using a dictionary or adding the `BOOL` as a property of your item would probably be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NSNumber BOOL `@YES` and `@NO` instead of an `NSString` of @"YES" and @"NO".

```
NSDictionary *test = @{@"key" : @YES};
```

To get the value:

```
BOOL keyBoolValue = [test[@"key"] boolValue];
NSLog(@"keyBoolValue: %i", keyBoolValue);

if (keyBoolValue == YES) {
    NSLog(@"true:");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"false:");
}
```

or

```
if ([test[@"key"] boolValue] == YES) { ...
```

Comment: How can you compare them?

Comment: Yes, it is redundant and can be removed. It is there to insure the answer example is clear. Clarity can be a virtue.